Imbalanced Dataset Correlation in Machine Learning
If there is an imbalanced dataset, I cannot figure out the correlation or dependency of the target column on different features. How can I check that?
I am using countplot but with that, I cannot figure out the solution actually as the dataset is imbalanced.
